# Two Volumes are created when I run a docker container with volume mapping

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am creating postgreSQL container using following command

```
sudo docker run -d --name=pg -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -e PGDATA=/pgdata -v pg:/pgdata postgres
```

After running this container when I check volumes by running following command

```
sudo docker volume ls

DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               6d283475c6fe923155018c847f2c607c464244cb6767dd37a579824cf8c7e612
local               pg
```

I get two volumes. pg volume is created in the command but what the second volume is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Docker Hub decomposition of the `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/latest/images/sha256-f018e9368b20e43b78fdb2913ac69058b0c1e97acee248d6b00765609237d6f6?context=explore) you will notice it has a declaration

```
VOLUME ["/var/lib/postgresql/data"]
```

If you don't explicitly mount something else on that directory, Docker will create an *anonymous volume* and mount it there for you.  This behaves identically to a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) except that it doesn't have a specific name.

`docker inspect` mostly dumps out low-level diagnostic information, but it should include the mount information, and you should see two volume mounts, one with the anonymous volume on the default PostgreSQL data directory and a second matching the explicit mount on `/pgdata`.